# node-formidable on end event in nodejs

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I am trying to write the stream data into my DB. Below is my code where as an input two files I am trying to upload. Both the files are getting saved in DB but before all DB operations gets completed, form.on("end") event (second DB call) is called.

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.onPart = function (part) {
        // First DB call
        var Obj = {
            'DBName': 'FILEDB',
            'collectionName': 'FILEDATA',
            'fileName': "File1"
        }
        dbapi(part, Obj, function (err, result) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err)
            else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
    }
form.on('end', function () {
        // second DB call
    });
```

How to call form.on('end') after all the form.onPart() DB calls are completed. Any help on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Helpful for you to understand what is happening with the two events. ==> the dbapi has a callback function which does not return/finish before the 'end' event is triggered for form.on.

There are many ways you can handle your need e.g. scheduling form.onPart and form.on to run in series - check out or google "series async control flow pattern in Node".  Without using async, the below snippet may solve your problem:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.onPart = function (part) {
    // First DB call
    var Obj = {
        'DBName': 'FILEDB',
        'collectionName': 'FILEDATA',
        'fileName': "File1"
    };
    dbapi(part, Obj, function (err, result) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log(result);
        }
        scheduleEndEvent();
    });
};
function scheduleEndEvent() {
form.on('end', function () {
        // second DB call
});
}
```

Try above and see if it works for you but what you really need is a good grasp of control flow patterns in Node.

I can confirm that async.series would be an elegant way to chain the events you are processing in the order you described.

See algorithm below:

```
async.series([
   function1,
   function2
], callback)
```